# Diffusion equation if f and φ are periodic the solution is also periodic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, periodic-functions

If I have the diffusion equation

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-D \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}=f(x,t) $$ with the initial condition $$u(x, 0) = φ(x).$$

How would I prove that if $f$ and $φ$ are p-periodic in $x$, that is for some $p > 0$ the identities f(x+p, t) = f(x, t)
and $φ(x + p)$ = $φ(x)$

hold for all x and t, then the solution is also p-periodic in x, i.e.
$$u(x + p, t) = u(x, t)$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $v(x, t) = u(x+p,t)-u(x,t)$, thus $v(x, 0)=0$ and
$$
\frac{\partial v} {\partial t} -D \frac{\partial^2 v} {\partial x^2}=0
$$
from which we conclude that $v(x, t) =0$ and thus $u(x+p,t)=u(x,t)$.

Edit: (more detailed)

1) Using periodicity of initial condition $\phi$ to find initial condition for $v$
$$
v(x, 0)= u(x+p,0)-u(x,0) = \phi(x+p)-\phi(x) = \phi(x)-\phi(x) =0
$$

2) Using periodicity of source $f$ to find equation for $v$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v(x,t)} {\partial t} 
&= \frac{\partial u(x+p,t)} {\partial t} - \frac{\partial u(x,t)} {\partial t}\\
&= D\frac{\partial^2 u(x+p,t)} {\partial x^2} +f(x+p,t) -D\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)} {\partial x^2} -f(x,t)\\
&=D\frac{\partial^2 v(x,t)} {\partial x^2} + f(x,t) - f(x,t)\\
&=D\frac{\partial^2 v(x,t)} {\partial x^2}
\end{align}

3) Uniqueness of solutions to the diffusion equation means that $v(x,t)=0$ is the only solution, and as such $u(x+p,t)=u(x,t)$

Comment: Hi thank you for that! would it be possible to include a few more steps between steps i'm just having trouble understanding it

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Am I able to conclude questions how you wrote 3) with "uniqueness of solutions mean that v(x,t)= 0 or would I not need to demonstrate 3. Thank you again by the way.

Comment: If you are trying to answer questions for a class in which you have been told about the uniqueness of solution then you won't need to prove that.

Comment: +1 but its $$\frac{\partial u(x,t)} {\partial t} $$ and not $\frac{\partial u(x+p,t)} {\partial t} $ in the first line point 2.  you should correct,Eddy.

Comment: Thanks for correction :)